# swift - retrieve objectId field causes fatal error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Here is my code:

```
    @IBAction func saveSettings(sender: AnyObject) {
    var settings:PFObject = PFObject(className: "Settings")
    settings["routes"] = routesSetting as String
    settings["sortBy"] = sortBySetting as String
    settings["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
    settings.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{(success:Bool!, error:NSError!) ->Void in
        if success != nil {
            NSLog("%@","OK-settings data saved")
            NSLog("%@",self.routesSetting as String)
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog("%@",error)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func updateSettings(sender: AnyObject) {

    var settings:PFObject = PFObject(className:"Settings")
    var id = settings["objectId"] as String
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Settings")

    println(settings)
    println(id)
    println(query)

    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(id) {
        (settings: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        } else {
            settings["routes"] = self.routesSetting as String
            settings["sortBy"] = self.sortBySetting as String
            settings.save()
        }
    }
```

I can run the saveSettings code with no issues.  I have set it up to run when a new user signs up with the application.  I have verified that a new row is inserted into the settings table in the Parse cloud DB.  But I would now like to simply UPDATE the single row instead of create a new row every time there is a save.  So I have been working on the updateSettings function.  I have followed the Parse documentation for updating objects (https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-updating/iOS).  When I click on the Update button to run the function, I get:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

The line it points to is:

```
var id = settings["objectId"] as String
```

I am a complete beginner to Parse.

Some recent additional information:

The results of the println statements:

```
<Settings: 0x7fd423805260, 
 objectId: new, localId: (null)> {
}
nil
<PFQuery: 0x7fd4217191f0>
```

So part of the problem is it is not retrieving the objectId?

Comment: If `settings["objectId"]` is nil, you cannot cast it to type String. You could cast it to type `String?` by writing `var id = settings["objectId"] as? String`. When working with Objective-C libraries in Swift, you often receive nil values, so you must store them in nullable variables.

Comment: I will try that.  But I can see the row in the table with an objectId - why would it be nil?

Comment: That still results the nil fatal error.  Could it be my query is incorrect? I am following the tutorial.

Comment: `settings` has no data when you instantiate it, so `id` will be nil. You could get an object without knowing its `id` by constructing a query, but it looks like you are trying to retrieve a specific object related to a single user or device. You will have to store the id of that object somewhere in order to get the object.

Comment: When I signup a new user I do populate a settings row with default values.  So when I populate that initial row upon singup I need to store the objectId at that point?

Answer (score 2):

`PFObject` has a **property** called "objectId", it is not stored in a dictionary, so you can return it as

```
var id = settings.objectId
```

Comment: Thank you - I will try this when I get home tonight - unfortunately no Macs at the office.

Comment: @lostinthebits ok, I hope it will solve your problem.